# MariaDB Aborted connection events

Tags: connectivity, mariadb-10.4

A windows server (2022) has MariaDB 10.4 running on it. In the Event Viewer for Windows logs > Application there are two events that happen every minute:

Aborted connection ### to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Aborted connection ### to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Note that '###' is a number that increases sequentially. Somehow this is related to the MariaDB service because the events don't appear when the service is stopped.

Is there any way to suppress these events?

Thanks

Comment: Is your server exposed to the public Internet? Do you have monitoring checking the server port?

Comment: Yes it is exposed to the public internet. There is no monitoring checking the server port that I'm aware of. Thanks

Comment: Then those log entries are from portscan bots. Expect hack attempts to follow. Databases should not be exposed to the internet unfiltered; deploy a firewall and restrict access to just the hosts that need it.

Comment: I have the same issue and it is related to the `zabbix-agent`. If `zabbix-agent` service is stopped then there are no messages in the logs. I didn't dig any further as far it isn't critical but it would be much appreciated if some cure for that issue will be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that some application connects on the TCP port to the server, and does not authenticate within a given timeout (which I think is 5 seconds by default). There is a way to suppress these messages. You set

log_warnings=1

in the my.ini. There is some documentation on verbosity, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/

But on your place, I'd be curious is this that connects on server port, and does not do anything.

Comment: Also was fixed in 
[MDEV-12274](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12274): Too many connections warning in error log [#2213](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/2213), but as of today, this hasn't made it into a release yet.

Comment: Adding log_warnings=1 fixed it. Thanks!